# pykube - RollingUpdater scale replicas

Tags: python, kubernetes

Utilising the pykube module https://github.com/kelproject/pykube

Does anyone know how to utilise the RollingUpdate#scale_up functions to increase deployment replicas?

I'm struggling to work out how to do it from the code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method as following is simpler:

```
import pykube
import operator

api = pykube.HTTPClient(pykube.KubeConfig.from_file("/root/.kube/config"))

deployment = pykube.Deployment.objects(api).filter(namespace="kube-system").get(name="test-busybox")

deployment.replicas = 1
deployment.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to work this out - to increase replicas to 3 you would do something like the following:

```
deployments = pykube.Deployment.objects(kubernetesApi).filter(namespace="my-namespace")

for dp in deployments:
    if dp.obj["metadata"]["name"] == "my-deployment":
        dp.replicas = 3
        pykube.Deployment(kubernetesApi, dp.obj).update()
```

Answer (score 0):

@eggsy84's answer will work but not elegant because you don't need to check all `Deployment` to update.

Here's the practical example if you want to update with `pykube`.

```
import pykube
import operator

api = pykube.HTTPClient(pykube.KubeConfig.from_file("~/.kube/config"))

name = "ms-999-ear2-071625"
deployment_obj = {
          "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
          "kind": "Deployment",
          "metadata": {
              "name": name,
          }
      }

deployment = pykube.Deployment(api, deployment_obj)
deployment.update()
deployment.replicas = 2
deployment.update()
```